# Fibonacci Sequence Java

Tags: java

I want to write a java program for  the Fibonacci sequence function.It is not working .Can someone help me please?It is working for small numbers only

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = input.nextInt();

    int e =fan(x);

            System.out.println(e);
    }

public static int fan(int e){ 
           int a =1;
           int b;
           int c = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<=e; i++) {
                b=c;
                c=b+a;
                a=b;
            }

        return c;


}

}
```

Comment: Define *not working*. It looks like it won't even compile.

Comment: when you write "for (i=1; i<b; i++) {", you expect 'i' to go from 1 to b. but b=1, so you don't even loop.

Comment: Also suspectible `c=b; c=b+a;`

Comment: For such simple problems you should attempt to debug them on your own in the future... it is crucial for your own education.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the i-th Fibonacci number?

Comment: Furthermore there is dead store `c=b;` followed by `c=b+a;` inside the loop.

Comment: first of all 'public static int fan(int i){}' is not a class

Comment: Neither is `public static void main(String[] args){}` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is implemented using BigInteger for big numbers.

```
public static String fan(int i) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
    if(i==0) return a.toString();

    for (int f = 1; f < i; f++) {
        BigInteger temp = b;
        b = a.add(b);
        a = temp;
    }
    return b.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args)

{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = input.nextInt();

    String i = fan(x);

    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci sequence can be implemented recursively as well. In this case it will be:

```
public int fibonacci(int n)  {
   if( (n == 0) || (n == 1) )
      return n;
   else
      return( fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2) );
}
```

and in BigIntegers it will be:

```
public BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
   if (n == 0) return BigInteger.ZERO;
   if (n == 1) return BigInteger.ONE;
   return fibonacci(n - 1).add(fibonacci(n - 2));
}
```

obviously iterative algorithms are faster than recursive...